# Can we disable azure function using feature flag

Tags: azure-functions, azure-feature-manager

I am looking to disable and enable a azure function using feature flags. Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the information what you have tried and any error you got or stuck at somewhere where you didn't know how to proceed further?

Comment: I haven’t tried yet. I am looking for whether is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to disable and enable a azure function using feature flags.

I believe we can do disabling and enabling the functions in an Azure Function Project using feature flags in the below process:

1. We have REST APIs to disable the function programmatically in the Azure Function app where Mayank has given the REST API Link along with the MS Doc for more information and steps for how to use in Code in [Q&A Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/833338/enabledisable-functions-in-azure-programmically-in.html).
2. Feature Flags can be used programmatically also with the help of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration`, `Microsoft.FeatureManagement` packages.

Feature Manager instance should be kept in DI Class by using the `FunctionsStartup` class.

There is a boilerplate code given by Microsoft on using the [feature flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) in Azure Functions to change the functionality in runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal#c-class-libraries which has a decorator for turning on or off functions without allowing them to be triggered.

edit: Here's an answer for what is supported with attributes: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/312

Comment: Liv, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)